# Getting Checkbox values when user edits form data. PHP

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have a form with checkboxes that users fill out and submit.  I then have another form that allows them to edit the information they submitted.  This second form pre-populates with the information they submitted on the first form.  This is fine with text fields, but how do I pre-populate the checkboxes?  I.e.  if they checked a checkbox on the first form, how do I get the second form to recognise that and display a checked checkbox?

I'm new to Php so sorry I can't be more technical with this query!

Thanks

Luke

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you have so far and what you've tried?

Comment: Add `checked="checked"` to the checkboxes you want to be checked

Comment: I was kind of stabbing in the dark a bit here but this doesn't work:-

Comment: `code`<label for="pool">Pool</label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="pool" id="pool" name="pool" <?php echo isset($_POST['pool']) ? "checked" : ""; ?>>`code`

Comment: Sorry, new to to stackoverflow.  Can't get code tags to work?! And thanks for fast reply!

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form, you have the data on the next page. So if theres a checkbox looking like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="over18" value="1" />
```

You have to check if the person selected the "over 18"-field.

```
if ($_POST['over18'] == '1') {
  $checked = 'checked="checked"';
} 
else {
  $checked = ''; //If it's not checked
}
```

Then your output for the checkbox looks like this:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="over18" value="1" ' . $is_checked .'/>';
```

So everytime the Checkbox is checked, the next page checks the Checkbox too.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  On the second form I have :--- `
if ($_POST['pool'] == 'Pool') {
  $is_checked = 'checked="checked"';
} 
else {
  $is_checked = ''; //If it's not checked
}    `

Comment: and also  <label for="pool">Pool</label>
          <?php echo '<input type="checkbox" id="pool" name="pool" value="Pool" ' . $is_checked .'/>'; ?>

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST);` and you will see how the var is built. Maybe the if-Statement is wrong...

Comment: Sorry, not too sure what you mean by "Try print_r($_POST);" I'm new to  Php etc... Thanks for help by the way!!

Comment: If you add the function `print_r($_POST);` somewhere to the second page, you will see how the Array $_POST looks like. Try it 2 times, one time without checking the box and one time with a checked box. The var will change and you only need to know when you need to add the `checked="checked"` thing.

Comment: Ok I think I'm making progress.  I can find out if the checkbox is checked or not, but I can't seem to assign the variable...  What is wrong with this if statement??

Comment: if (get_post_meta($post_to_edit->ID,'pool', true)) : 
     $checked = 'checked="checked"';


 endif;